# Sequelize transaction include not working when creating objects?

Tags: sql-server, typescript, sequelize.js

I'm adding objects into a SQL Server database with Sequelize.
I perform all operations in one single transaction. When I want to retrieve the inserted objects, the associated models aren't fetched. But if I query them separately, they are found.

This code works:

```js
 const model = await SequelizeModel.findOne({
    where: {
      name: step.relation.model,
    },
    transaction,
  });
  const modelField = await SequelizeModelField.findOne({
    where: {
      name: step.relation.field,
    },
    transaction,
  });

  const referenceModel = await SequelizeModel.findOne({
    where: {
      name: step.relation.referenceModel,
    },
    transaction,
  });

  const referenceModelField = await SequelizeModelField.findOne({
    where: {
      name: step.relation.referenceField,
    },
    transaction,
  });
```

But this code doesn't return the include:

```js
const modelField = await SequelizeModelField.findOne({
    where: {
      name: step.relation.field,
    },
    include: [
      {
        model: SequelizeModel,
        where: {
          name: step.relation.model,
        },
      },
    ],
    transaction,
  });

  const referenceModelField = await SequelizeModelField.findOne({
    where: {
      name: step.relation.referenceField,
    },
    include: [
      {
        model: SequelizeModel,
        where: {
          name: step.relation.referenceModel,
        },
      },
    ],
    transaction,
  });
```

Generated SQL of the two selects:

```sql
SELECT
    [SequelizeModelField].[id],
    [SequelizeModelField].[name],
    [SequelizeModelField].[type],
    [SequelizeModelField].[length],
    [SequelizeModelField].[searchable],
    [SequelizeModelField].[default],
    [SequelizeModelField].[nullable],
    [SequelizeModelField].[unique],
    [SequelizeModelField].[primary],
    [SequelizeModelField].[autoIncrement],
    [SequelizeModelField].[tokenField],
    [SequelizeModelField].[encryption],
    [SequelizeModelField].[modelId],
    [SequelizeModelField].[created_at],
    [SequelizeModelField].[updated_at],
    [model].[id] AS [_0],
    [model].[name] AS [_1],
    [model].[tableName] AS [_2],
    [model].[ignoreFields] AS [_3],
    [model].[auditEnabled] AS [_4],
    [model].[created_at] AS [_5],
    [model].[updated_at] AS [_6]
FROM
    [__model_fields] AS [SequelizeModelField]
    INNER JOIN [__models] AS [model] ON [SequelizeModelField].[modelId] = [model].[id]
    AND [model].[name] = N'endpoints'
WHERE
    [SequelizeModelField].[name] = N'appconfig_id'
ORDER BY
    [SequelizeModelField].[id] OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

and:

```sql
SELECT
    [SequelizeModelField].[id],
    [SequelizeModelField].[name],
    [SequelizeModelField].[type],
    [SequelizeModelField].[length],
    [SequelizeModelField].[searchable],
    [SequelizeModelField].[default],
    [SequelizeModelField].[nullable],
    [SequelizeModelField].[unique],
    [SequelizeModelField].[primary],
    [SequelizeModelField].[autoIncrement],
    [SequelizeModelField].[tokenField],
    [SequelizeModelField].[encryption],
    [SequelizeModelField].[modelId],
    [SequelizeModelField].[created_at],
    [SequelizeModelField].[updated_at],
    [model].[id] AS [_0],
    [model].[name] AS [_1],
    [model].[tableName] AS [_2],
    [model].[ignoreFields] AS [_3],
    [model].[auditEnabled] AS [_4],
    [model].[created_at] AS [_5],
    [model].[updated_at] AS [_6]
FROM
    [__model_fields] AS [SequelizeModelField]
    INNER JOIN [__models] AS [model] ON [SequelizeModelField].[modelId] = [model].[id]
    AND [model].[name] = N'appconfig'
WHERE
    [SequelizeModelField].[name] = N'id'
ORDER BY
    [SequelizeModelField].[id] OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Output from `modelField.get({ plain: true })`:

```json
{
  id: 20,
  name: "appconfig_id",
  type: "INT",
  length: null,
  searchable: null,
  default: null,
  nullable: null,
  unique: null,
  primary: null,
  autoIncrement: null,
  tokenField: null,
  encryption: false,
  modelId: 2,
  created_at: "2024-02-17T11:14:40.807Z",
  updated_at: "2024-02-17T11:14:40.807Z",
}
```

The associations are defined like this:
SequelizeModel

```js
@HasMany(() => SequelizeModelField, {
  onDelete: "CASCADE",
})
fields: SequelizeModelField[];
```

And SequelizeModelField:

```js
@ForeignKey(() => SequelizeModel)
@Column
modelId: number;

@BelongsTo(() => SequelizeModel)
model: SequelizeModel;
```

Initialisation code:

```js
if (environment.databaseType == "mssql") {
      dialectOptions["options"] = {
        trustServerCertificate: environment.databaseDialectSSL,
        appName: environment.swaggerTitle ?? "No Code API",
      };
    }
    

    this.sequelize = new Sequelize({
      host: environment.databaseType == "sqlite" ? null : environment.databaseHost,
      dialect: environment.databaseType as Dialect,
      dialectOptions: dialectOptions,
      database: environment.databaseName,
      port: environment.databasePort,
      username: environment.databaseUsername,
      password: environment.databasePassword,
      storage: environment.databaseType == "sqlite" ? environment.databaseHost : null,
      minifyAliases: environment.databaseType != "sqlite" ? true : false,
      logging: console.log,
      pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        idle: 10000,
      },
      models: [
        SequelizeMigration,
        SequelizeMigrationStep,
        SequelizeMigrationStepField,
        SequelizeMigrationStepModel,
        SequelizeMigrationStepRelation,
        SequelizeMigrationStepRoute,
        SequelizeMigrationStepRole,
        SequelizeMigrationStepRoleCheck,
        SequelizeMigrationStepRoleField,
        SequelizeModel,
        SequelizeModelField,
        SequelizeModelFieldRelation,
        SequelizeModelRoute,
        SequelizeModelRouteTrigger,
        SequelizeModelRole,
        SequelizeModelRoleCheck,
        SequelizeModelRoleField,
        SequelizeView,
        SequelizeViewRoute,
        SequelizeViewRole,
        SequelizeViewRoleCheck,
      ],
      define: {
        createdAt: "created_at",
        updatedAt: "updatedAt",
      },
    });

    await this.sequelize.authenticate();
    await this.sequelize.sync();

    return this.sequelize;
```

Am I missing something here or is this expected behaviour when using a transaction with Sequelize?

Comment: Could you show and check out the generated SQL for the query that does not return included model?

Comment: @Anatoly added the generated SQL as requested.

Comment: Do the generated SQL queries return the expected records?

Comment: Yes they do, but not the included attributes. This same code does work against a Postgres database

Comment: Could you show the output to console this code `modelField.get({ plain: true })`?

Comment: Please don't add in the comments, only in the post itself

Comment: Added it to the post

Comment: I see strange aliases for included model fields like `_0`. Did you set some explicit options in Sequelize instance or maybe you defined default scopes?

Comment: Added initialisation code

Comment: Can you turn on `minifyAliases` to true and compare generated SQL with the previous one? Will it be any difference?

Comment: I've tried it and no difference. So no lead on that I guess.

Comment: Could you use different DBMS and compare the results?

Comment: I forgot to mention, but this code works without issue on Postgres. I've also noticed that in another part of the code, include doesn't work either with MSSQL. Looks somehow it's broken when using MSSQL.

Comment: Looks like it. Is there any other MSSQL drivers that could be used with Sequelize?

Comment: I wouldn't know. Are there any others?

Comment: Just my guess. If not - that's bad. Can you try a minimal example with two models, Sequelize, MSSQL and *no* sequelize-typescript in a separate project?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `minifyAliases: true`! I was a bit confused and didn't read the code properly. `minifyAliases` was always `true` because of the `sqlite` comparison we had. When `false`, include works normally.